# MMORPG development and server side logic, update all Game Objects?

Tags: c#, .net

I have designed Multiplayers Games before, but now I wanted to create an MMORPG Architecture for learning/challenge purpose. I want to go as far as simulate hundreds(or a couple thousands) of concurrent players on a single server.

So far so good except that right now I am facing a problem to figure out a good way to update all game objects on the Server as often and as fast as possible.

By Game Objects I mean all Players, Mobs, Bullets.

The problem is that all Players, Mobs, Bullets are stored in a Collections on the Server Side Memory for faster processing, and iterating throught all of them to check for collisions, update health, update movement, etc... is taking way too long.

Lets say I have 1000 players and there is 10000 mobs in the whole world and all players and creatures are responsible for creating 5 other game objects(no more no less) such as bullets.

That would give (1000 + 10000) * 5 = 55000 game objects in a collection.

Iterating throught all objects, to update them, take forever(a couples minutes) on a Dual-Core HT i5 with 4gb RAM. This is wrong.

When iterating, the code look like this(pseudo):

```
for(int i = 0; i < gameobjects.Count; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < gameobjects.Count; j++) {
      // logic to verify if gameobjects[i] is in range of
      // gameobjects[j]
  }
}
```

As an optimization, I am thinking about dividing my game objects in different zones and collections but that wouldn't fix the problem where I need to update all objects several times per seconds.

How should i proceed to update all game objects on the server side? I did heavy search to find interesting game design patterns but no results so far. :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would go with an event based design that only requires an object to be updated when needed.

Comment: For the case of the range check code, you should use a Quad Tree ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_tree) (or similar) structure. That'll prevent it from always being N^2.

Comment: Notice that even if the approach is not correct, I would like to mention that you are not using 2 cores in that loop, no multithreading involved, you are wasting 50% of your processor power.

Comment: Sure @Fire-Dragon-DoL, but that would not solve the core problem, at best it would take 4-5 minutes, instead of 8.

Comment: @eandersson: Yes, it's obvious. I just wanted to point out that you can't expect good CPU usage if your code doesn't care about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Fire-Dragon-DoL. I was effectively considering to take advantage of multi-core at an optimisation phase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would change the design completely and implement an event base design. This has many advantages, the obvious one is that you will only need to update the objects that are actually being interacted with. As you will always have a majority of the game objects in an MMO game being idle, or not seen at all.

There is no reason why you should calculate objects that are not visible on any players screen. That would be insane and require a server farm that you most likely cannot afford. Instead you can try to predict movement. Or store a list of all objects that are currently not interacted with and update these less frequently.

If a player can't see an object you can teleport the unit over large distances instead of having it travel smoothly. Essentially moving the unit over huge distances within the confined area that the object is allowed to move. Making it look like the object is moving freely even when the object is not visible to the players. Usually this would be triggered as an event when a new player enters, or leaves a zone.

You can achieve this by simply calculating the time since the last update and predict how far the object would have traveled, as if it was visible to the player. This is especially useful for objects or NPCs that has a set route, as it makes the calculations much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll definitely think about a way to implement an Events Based Commands Logic along with dividing my World in Zones/Sub-Zones inside a Grid.

Comment: Yea, you would definitely need to combine this with a zone system. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is running that slow, not just because  it is checking all N objects, but because it checking all possible interactions of objects, and that takes N^2 calculations =  3 025 000 000 in your sample.

One way to reduce this number of checks would be to put the object in your game world into a grid, so that objects that are not in the same or aligned cells cannot interact with each other.

Also, your current code checks each interaction twice, you can easily fix this by starting loop from i in your inner cycle:

```
for(int i = 0; i < gameobjects.Count; i++) 
  for(int j = i; j < gameobjects.Count; j++)
```

Comment: I'll investigate the idea of Grid when dividing the world in different Zones and Sub-Zones. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looping over 55,000 objects shouldn't be too slow. Obviously, you are doing too much stuff too often over those objects and probably doing stuff that shouldn't always be done.

For example, if there is no players around a mob, should it really be calculated? 
(if a tree falls in a forest and there's nobody around, does it really make a sound?)

Also, lot of objects might not need to be updated at every loop. Players for instance could be left to the client to calculate and only be "verified" once every 1-2 seconds. Dumping all the player's collision to the client would make your server workload much easier to handle. Same things for player's bullet or raycast. In return, it also makes the game much more fluid for the players.

Does mobs when following a path need to be tested for collision or can the path's nodes be enough?

Testing every objects against every other objects is terrible. Does all mobs has to be tested vs all other mobs or only specific type or faction need to be tested? Can you split your world into smaller zone that would only test mobs within it against objects also in it?

There's huge work done in MMO server's code to make it work properly. The optimizations done is sometime insane, but as long as it works.

Comment: You are clever, I knew someone was going to talk about the 'Falling Tree in the Forest' thing. The point is that I am still considering if mobs, even if not In the visual scope of any players, would still be moving around, building nest or migrating. But again, I could probably just implement the logic differently.

Comment: @Armz Alright... But can you simplify their loop, movement, collision if they are not near a player? If they go to a position, you could only interpolate between two point. No collision, no animation, no raycast, no line of sight... Lot of thing can be done to ease up the workload.

Comment: Absolutly, I will find a way to implement the out-of-visual-scope logic. Thanks!